# How to fill default commit message in TortoiseGit?

Tags: git, bitbucket, tortoisegit

I was unable to find, how to set default commit message in TortoiseGit:

[image]

seems the default git method doesn't work:

```
[commit]
    template = ~/message.txt
```

Comment: This are several question in one.

Comment: ok, corrected..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1) The git default mechanism works in general, however, there seems to be a bug with `~/` - use an absolute path as a workaround, i.e.

```
C:/Users/user/git_message.txt
```

2) On the commit dialog the "Commit" button is a menu dropdown button. Choose `Commit & Push there` (cf. https://tortoisegit.org/docs/tortoisegit/tgit-dug-commit.html).

Comment: 1) have you test/got it working?   2) Yes, i know that, however i wanted to do that directly with rigth click on file, but unlike the screenshot, there was "PUSH" directly (with the preset default message).

Comment: A fix for 1) will be in the next release.

Comment: I confirm using 
[commit]
 template = ~/git_message.txt
in C:/Users/user/git_message.txt works